# Why is embedding_lookup better than one hot encoding with a linear transformation?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I think I'm missing something obvious here but would love some help figuring this out.

Say I have a million words and want to embed them as part of my model. 
With TF I can do an embedding lookup, though I need to provide a matrix of size [1m*space_size]. So for 50 dimensions that comes out to 50M trainable parameters. 
On the other hand I can one hot encode the a million words with a vector of dimension 20. I can embed that into a a space of dimension 50 with a [20*50] matrix for 1K parameters. Much cheaper. Since the weights of this matrix are still trainable, I'd expect to learn something about the words and if I need more capacity I can increase the size of the space.

That's in theory, in practice I tried and the model didn't learn anything. So my question is, why? 
Thanks

Comment: When using embedding, make sure a million words form a meaningful text, not just a list of words from some dictionary in arbitrary / sorted order.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that you can encode a million words with a 20 digit binary number. But one-hot encoding is not binary. It means that only a single digit in the whole vector can be one and the rest are zero. That digit indicates the index of the word. So you would need a 2 million length vector to encode 2 million words. Then you would need a matrix of 2 million x 50 for the model parameters.

Using the 20 digit binary representation is problematic because you are arbitrarily assigning certain words to be closer to each other in the 20-dim space. It's better to let the model learn these associations rather than pre-defining them.

Comment: The first part makes sense to me.

Comment: The first part makes sense to me. Thanks. 
Regarding the second paragraph. I don't understand the difference between assigning a random vector in a space via embedding and assiging a fixed, small encoding and learning a transformation from the encoding to the embedding space. Any clues ?

Comment: Similar vectors in the input will get mapped to similar vectors in the output. When you use one-hot encoding all vectors are equally similar/dissimilar. When you use your fixed encoding you've predetermined that certain words must be similar to each other if they have similar binary encodings. This is not something that you wont. Also, 20x50 parameters is way too small to encode useful information about language. You will need many more parameters to memorize that information.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Stochastic Gradient Descent seems to require significant overparameterization in order to learn, here's one paper along those lines -- ["Big Neural Networks Waste Capacity"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3583)

Comment: I'll take a look though from the abstract I'm not sure this is the case. 
I compensated for smaller embedding layers by increasing the size of layers further down the network.